# textfield setEnabled with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I have a UISwitch, witch among other things, disables a UITextfield.
When using NSUserDefaults, I manage the switch to remember its current state (on/off)

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setBool:[sender isOn]
     forKey:MyPrefKey];
```

But how to remember that the textfiled was enabled?
Using "setBool" is out of the question, and I can't figure how to use setObject.

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:[textField setEnabled:NO]
         forKey:MyPrefKey];
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is using `setBool` out of the question?

Either should work, but you should remember to synchronize the user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Also in your 2nd example there is an error, you should be setting the flag to `[textField isEnabled]` instead of `setEnabled:NO`, since this returns void. You also are trying to pass in a primitive `BOOL`, it should be wrapped in an `NSNumber` to be stored as an object

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[textField isEnabled]]
         forKey:MyPrefKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```